# How to learn iOS programming without storyboards?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I started learning iOS development three months ago to build a final project for a class of mine. A few of the TAs recommended, since I was using storyboards, to learn how to program iOS without storyboards, completely programatically. I kept getting SIGBART errors, which forced me to delete the button/field in question and then do the exact same thing again in order to recalibrate the storyboard. I would much rather do it programmatically and it work the first time.

Anyways, how would I go about learning how to do everything programmatically instead of with XIB/NIBs or storyboarding? Every tutorial or book I seem to come across uses one of these two methods, as they seem more visual and easy for beginners to pick up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answers that do not answer the question (and instead encourage the use of storyboards) are not appropriate.

Comment: You need to narrow this question down to something specific. It's far too broad in its current state. There's nothing special to do everything in code. Just do it. I've never used IB in over 5 years of iOS development.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: the question itself is not answerable in terms of the rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: I wrote a blog post exploring Objective-C iOS applications without Storyboards here (including launch screens): https://www.jviotti.com/2022/12/14/writing-objective-c-ios-apps-without-storyboards.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been building in XCode this way for a while now, I don't use any Xib files in my development.

It's pretty straight forward to get started just follow these steps:

1. Create a new single view Application
2. In the navigator, delete the two '.storyboard' files.
3. In the '.plist' file under Supporting Files, remove the two Strings relating to "Main storyboard file base name..."
4. In your 'AppDelegate.m', include your custom UIViewController at the top and then
5. Update the 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method to look like:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{        
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     UIViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
     self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
   }
   ```

Running the application should show you the new screen (MyViewController) which has a black background by default.

Inside your UIViewController, you can now start scripting what elements you need inside say the 'viewDidLoad' method. Some Examples below:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

      UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
      myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      [self.view addSubview:myView];

      UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 180, 50)];
      myLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
      myLabel.text = @"Example";
      myLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
      [myView addSubview:myLabel];
    }
```

There are lots of coding examples on the net. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start reading apples class references to everything you are about to use. When you do things programmatically, it is very important to know the propertys and methods to work with.
2. Add "programmatically" to every google search.
3. Get used to setting a frame to almost everything.

Storyboards are nowhere near beginner material in my understanding. It requires very deep insight on how things will work out and what is actually possible (despite what xcode trys to fool you in). You may change font and color of something and think it will actually change, silly you. 
Especially debugging can be a hassle. I remember starting over my first storyboard project 3 times because it was fubar (as far as i could debug at that time).
Those things can be very confusing right at the beginning.

Nib/Xibs are much stabler to work with in my experience so you may want to try them out for a view or two.

Later on, you don't want to miss storyboards though. You can skip hundreds of line of code and visual debugging with a few mouseclicks and it gives you great overview with larger projects.